# Как сделать такое в своем приложении?

Tags: android

Хочу реализовать такой же короткий обзор функций при первом запуске, покажу на примере Telegram:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам нужна подобного рода инструкция пользователя, и не хотите тратить много времени - есть хорошо документированная [библиотека](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro).